# Firestore document exist returns false result in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Not a single document or collection exist in my Firestore database,
but when calling this code it prints out "Document exist == true. User data:  (user.data())"

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

error.

```
let reference = database.collection("users").document(currentUser.uid)

reference.getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
    guard let user = snapshot else {
        print("Document exist == false")
        return
    }

    print("Document exist == true. User data:  \(user.data())")
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @CMont Thanks, that helped me to understand the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [exists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot#/c:objc(cs)FIRDocumentSnapshot(py)exists) method in addition to checking that a non null snapshot was returned:

```
let reference = database.collection("users").document(currentUser.uid)

reference.getDocument { (snapshot, error) in

    guard
        let snapshot = snapshot,
        let user = snapshot.exists ? snapshot : nil
    else {
        print("Document exist == false")
        return
    }
    print("Document exist == true. User data:  \(user.data())")
}
```

Comment: Can someone explain me this line let user = snapshot.exists ? snapshot : nil please. What does the ? do in this case. Searched Swift documentation but could not find anything.

Comment: It is the "ternary operator", as found in most languages. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60. I can understand that searching for "?" can be painful ...